# Combination of power button and volume up button in android

Tags: android

Like the combination of Power button and Volume down button - takes a screenshot of the phone... similarly I am trying to access volume up and power button long pressed keys in my app and give a shortcut.  Is this possible?

I know how to get the access of both buttons individually but not combined at the same time.

```
      @Override
      public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER){
        Log.w("LongPress", "power LONG PRESS");
    }

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        Log.w("LongPress", "Volume Up LONG PRESS");
    }

    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
   }

    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        event.startTracking();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```

How to get the combination done here '&&' doesn't work?

Comment: you need to keep track of which keys are down, not just what got pressed at this moment.

Comment: @MarcB if you are taking about the onKeyDown then I have also added it. if it is different can you tell me?

Comment: @TheDevMan: use combination of `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` to check which keys are pressed.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand programming under android, but I see it uses Java classes, so try this

```
public class BitKeys implements KeyListener {

    private BitSet keyBits = new BitSet(256);

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent event) {
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        keyBits.set(keyCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent event) {
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        keyBits.clear(keyCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(final KeyEvent event) {
        // don't care
    }

    public boolean isKeyPressed(final int keyCode) {
        return keyBits.get(keyCode);
    }

}
```

I found this here :
[handle multiple key presses ignoring repeated key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851155/handle-multiple-key-presses-ignoring-repeated-key)