# Android event for combination of Volume and power button pressing

Tags: android

How can I get the combination event of volume button and power button in android? Is it possible?If yes then how?
When I key down both the buttons then,how should I get an event in the application so that I can perform any action on this event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15594482/752320

Comment: link is fine but when I press one of the key either power button or volume,it is taking key down or key up event of the recently select button.If I press both the buttons at once then it is not coming in keyDown or keyPress or Key up events.So from where should I take this combination event.