# handling two key presses simultaneously in android

Tags: android

I am building an android application in which i have to listen the event when power key and volume down key are pressed simultaneously.Is it possible to listen simultaneous key presses in android ?

I have implemented it but it is working for only single key event.
Anyone who knows about this please share it or provide suggestions.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: can u share some information about how to achieve it.I have searched a lot but failed to get appropriate result.

Comment: You can ovveride the 
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     switch (keyCode) {
     }
     return false;
} 
and manage the two key simultanly

Comment: [Some relevant info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594482/combination-of-power-button-and-volume-up-button-in-android) , [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851155/handle-multiple-key-presses-ignoring-repeated-key) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752999/how-do-i-handle-multiple-key-presses-in-java/753078#753078)