# addKeyListener to Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, animation, keylistener

I want to `addKeyListener` to a `JPanel` but when I press two keys at the same time, just one of them executes. What is the solution to this problem - press two keys at the same time?

I have a class that extends JPanel

```
this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            upPlayer2();
    }  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A ){

            leftPlayer2();
        }

}
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: I know you have tried yourself but could you please show that to us :) so that we can understand that you have tried and have minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/753078/1068167

Comment: Keyevents are fired one at a time with/without masks (alt, ctrl, etc). Your code will not work, e is one event it cannot possibly be another event in the same call to keyTyped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings.

See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and solutions.